# Nice way to draw subgroup lattice for $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have to draw a lattice of the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. I have done this, but it is rather messy looking and hard to follow, with lines crisscrossing all over the place. Is there an easy way to format the lattice of subgroups for this group to make it less messy?

Comment: Where can we see what you obtain?

Comment: Well, $G$ has 14 proper nontrivial subgroups. $7$ of order 2, generated by each of the non identity elements. Call these $B_i$, $i=1,\dots,7$. It also has $7$ subgroups of order $4$, generated by pairs of the non identity elements. Call these $C_i$. Each of the $B_i$ is a subgroup of 3 of the $C_i$ and each of the $C_i$ is a supergroup of 3 of the $B_i$. This results in a busy and messy lattice. I was wondering if there is a way to align the $B_i$ under the $C_i$ so that the lattice looks nicer.

Comment: Is tthere a link to see what you've done? Anyway this is a question for TeX LaTeX Stack Exchange, I think.

Comment: As you describe it yourself, there is a limit to how nice this can look. That said, try GraphViz (it should only take a minute at most to plug in the needed edges) and see how it looks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph on these 14 proper non-trivial subgroups is the famous Heawood graph. Do a google image search and you can see many nice pictures. (It is non-planar though, so there will always be some edges crossing.)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted! I'd upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet I'm afraid.